# Transaction management with DAOs

Tags: java, mysql, transactions, dao

In my Java application's DAO layer I have two DAO classes `EmployeeDAO` and `BankDAO`. I need to control/handle their database transactions. I use connection pooling to get database connections.

EmployeeDAO class:

```
public class EmployeeDAO {
    String name;
    String empCode;
    int age;

    // Getters & Setters
}
```

BankDAO class:

```
public class BankDAO {
    String bankName;
    String acNo;
    String empCode;

    // Getters & Setters
}
```

Let's say I am going to store an Employee and Bank account details related to that employee in two database tables. First I save employee and second I save bank details and *if an error occurs* when storing bank details I need to **rollback** complete transaction.

How to manage this sort of transaction while using DAOs?

Comment: Make sure they use the same database connection.

Comment: yes, I am using the same database connection.

Comment: [DAO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_access_object) class normally receive a class domain objects [POJO or JavaBean](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_Old_Java_Object), which contain the fields of the table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using plain JDBC, what you could do is share the same instance of `Connection` in the two instances of the DAO classes.

```
public class EmployeeDAO {

    private Connection conn;

    public void setConnection(Connection conn) {
        this.conn = conn;
    }

    ...
}

public class BankDAO {

    private Connection conn;

    public void setConnection(Connection conn) {
        this.conn = conn;
    }

    ...
}
```

In the client code, first you need to create a `Connection` object instance. Next, you need start the transaction, with `conn.setAutoCommit(false);`. Pass the `Connection` object instance to the both DAO classes. If no errors occurs in any operation, `conn.commit();`, otherwise, `conn.rollback();`

e.g.:

```
Connection conn = null;
try {
    // getConnection from pool

    conn.setAutoCommit(false);

    EmployeeDAO employeeDAO = new EmployeeDAO();
    employeeDAO.setConnection(conn);

    BankDAO bankDAO = new BankDAO();
    bankDAO.setConnection(conn);

    // save employee

    // save bank details

    conn.commit();

catch(Exception e) {
    if (conn != null) {
        conn.rollback();
    }
} finally {
    if (conn != null) {
        conn.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Remember that `Connection#rollback` and `Connection#close` can throw SQLException and should be inside a `try-catch` block

Answer (score 2):

When you open a connection from the database, you can start a new transaction using the method `[Connection#setAutoCommit][1](false)`, do all your insert/update/delete operations and execute commit to save all these changes, in case of an error you can rollback all the actions or to a savepoint. Here is an exampleof what I'm saying:

```
public void saveSomeData(DAOClass daoObject) {

    Connection con = null;
    try {
        con = getConnectionFromDBPool(); //get the connection from the connection pool
        con.setAutoCommit(false);
        //start your transaction
        PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareCall("insert into tablex values(?, ?)");
        ps.setInt(1, daoObject.getAttribute1());
        ps.setString(2, daoObject.getAttribute2());
        ps.execute();
        //add another insert/update/delete operations...
        //at the end, you commit the transaction
        con.commit();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        //start a rollback
        if (con != null) {
            try {
                con.rollback();
            } catch (Exception ex) {
            }
        }
        //handle the exception
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (con != null) {
            try {
                con.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Another hint: you should close all the resources manually before closing the connection. This code is just explanatory, but I have should close the prepared statement after using it.

More info about handling transactions:

- [Using Transactions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/transactions.html)

Comment: Hi Luiggi, I'd like to know if daoObject.getAttribute1() can it be replaced with daoObject.getParameter or I have to do it separately at the Controller layer?

Comment: @KarenGoh yes you can.

Comment: But, I'd have to use HTTPRequest req as one of the parameters before I can do that right ?  If I put everything there as one method, how is my Controlller layer coming in later ?