# Transaction handling in DAO or Service layer using plain JDBC

Tags: java, jdbc, transactions, dao

Imagine I have classes `Account` and `Payment`.

Class **Account**

```
public class Account {
    private Integer id;
    private Integer accountHolderId;
    private BigDecimal balance;
    private Byte status;  // 0: account is fine, 1: locked, can't make payments.

    // Getters and Setters
}
```

Class **Payment**

```
public class Payment {
    private Integer id;
    private BigDecimal amount;
    private Integer senderId;
    private Integer receiver;
    private Integer paymentStatusId;

    // Getters and Setters
}
```

**DAO layer** has `AccountDao` and `PaymentDao` classes which implement CRUD methods. The next one is **Service layer** that has `AccountService` and `PaymentService` classes, that make additional actions on top of the DAO classes.

Since I am working with currency/money I am using [transactions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/transactions.html). I use them in my **DAO classes**.

My `DaoFactory` class has a method `createConnection()` that returns a Connection object for each specific DaoFactory (e.g. `MySqlDaoFactory`), that has enabled transaction feature using `connection.setAutoCommit(false);`. So every time I make a connection to the database I manually use `commit()` and `rollback()` methods.

---

### Question

Let's say I want to make a payment from one account (sender) to another (receiver). The scenario looks as following:

1. Check if `sender.status == 0`, which means it is unlocked and can send payments.
2. Check whether `he has more or equals amount of money` on his balance that he wants to send.
3. Withdraw this amount of money from his account.
4. Check if `receiver.status == 0`, which means it is unlocked and can receive money.
5. Deposit amount of money on receiver's account.
6. Change payment status to 1, which is successful.

This scenario tells that WE USE TWO DAO INSTANCES: `AccountDao` and `PaymentDao` and call methods from these instances. When I implement this scenario in `PaymentService` is it a proper way of implementing transactions?

Comment: This question looks like it might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10792684/transaction-management-with-daos

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of [Transaction management with DAOs](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10792684/217324). Look at the answers and see how nasty the solutions are, and think hard about using something like Spring.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are not working with some framework, like [Spring Transaction](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html) (which I would strong recommend you to use), I would recommend you do the following:

1. Use just one DAO class to make all the business process that you need and use the transaction just there.
2. Create the Connection in the Service layer and pass it as parameter through all the DAOs that you need in the business process. I dont like this way, because you will delegate the connection control to a service layer, nor a Data Access one.
3. Change the JDBC to use [Spring Transaction](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html), it will allow you to annote the methods that will be in the same transaction in the service layer, despite they are located in different DAOs. This works because Spring will control the Connection, so it'll inject the same connection through the DAOs. Take a look at this [example](http://www.journaldev.com/2603/spring-transaction-management-jdbc-example)

Its more a question of design preference then which one is correct

Comment: This sounds like a solution, but I am also worried about using a Connection object in Service layer.

Comment: Dont do this...I would not do this in my code, I would look for another solutions :p

Comment: How about creating an additional layer, don't know how to call it, but the layer that will be between **Service** and **DAO** layers to achieve what I want. Is it ok to make architecture more complicated by adding such a layer?

Comment: Another Dao that call both Daos passing the connections as parameter? Thats a solution too